# class_exists(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($class) of type string is deprecated

Tags: docker, authentication, yii2, deprecated, yii2-advanced-app

I had this newly installed Yii2 advanced and want to know if anyone of you ever encountered this error after login from the frontend?

What solution did you do to solve this issue?

Below is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.2.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/codeception": "^4.0",
        "codeception/module-asserts": "^1.0",
        "codeception/module-yii2": "^1.0",
        "codeception/module-filesystem": "^1.0",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.5.0 || ~1.1.0",
        "symfony/browser-kit": ">=2.7 <=4.2.4"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this error? in wich line of wich file?

Comment: I was able to solve it by downgrading my php version to 7.2. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like as of php 8.1 you can't put null values in the class_exists function.
To fix that issue, in file \vendor\yiisoft\yii2-debug\src\panels\UserPanel.php replace line 90/91

```
        if (!is_object($this->filterModel)
            && class_exists($this->filterModel)
```

with

```
        if (!is_object($this->filterModel) && $this->filterModel !== null
            && class_exists($this->filterModel)
```

It's not good solution because we are editing the source code of yii, but works :)
It is possible that version 2.0.46 of Yii will fix this

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Yii2 is not compatible with PHP version 8.1.
I had to go back to version 7.4 of PHP in my macbook

Answer (score 0):

> it is fixed in 634b9cc5e89bcc65091fe25ea2b5538b5bc5ce76, so when new release comes out it will be fixed, in the meantime you can use "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "dev-master#..."

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/issues/482